# How do I generate a QR image with RQRCode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, qr-code

How can I generate a `.png` of a QR code instead of an HTML Table?

This is my view to input the text for the QR code. (new.html.erb)

```
<%= form_for :qr_code, url: qr_codes_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :text %>
  <%= f.text_field :text %>
<%= f.submit %>
```

And this is the view to view the QR code as an HTML table (create.html.erb)

```
<% @qr.modules.each_index do |x| %>
  <tr>
    <% @qr.modules.each_index do |y| %>
      <% if @qr.dark?(x,y) %>
        <td class="black"/>
      <% else %>
        <td class="white"/>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

This is the controller for the QR code (qr_codes_controller.rb)

```
class QrCodesController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    @qr = RQRCode::QRCode.new(qr_code_params[:text], size: 4)
  end

  private

  def qr_code_params
    params.require(:qr_code).permit(:text)
  end
end
```

Comment: What problems are you running into? What isn't working? I assume you read the documentation on how to generate a png https://github.com/whomwah/rqrcode#png

Comment: Yes, I've read the documentation. I don't know where to add the lines for saving it as a PNG or how to add a link in my view to Download the PNG. Thank you so much for your response.